# Destructor not being called on a class copy with a different GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, cygwin, mingw, destructor

I have a class that has the copy constructor overloaded: `SomeClass::SomeClass (const SomeClass &copy) ...`

```
SomeClass s1;
s1.allocateCstring ("1 2325 7 8 9");
{
    SomeClass s2 = s1;
}
```

When compiled with g++ version `Target: x86_64-pc-cygwin`, destructors of `s1` and `s2` are invoked. But when i compile with g++ version `Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32`, only the destructor of `s1` is invoked. As a consequence  Is this some kind of a bug i'm experiencing? Full -v output for both:

x86_64-pc-cygwin:

```
$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-pc-cygwin
Configured with: /cygdrive/i/szsz/tmpp/gcc/gcc-6.4.0-5.x86_64/src/gcc-6.4.0/configure --srcdir=/cygdrive/i/szsz/tmpp/gcc/gcc-6.4.0-5.x86_64/src/gcc-6.4.0 --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --localstatedir=/var --sysconfdir=/etc --docdir=/usr/share/doc/gcc --htmldir=/usr/share/doc/gcc/html -C --build=x86_64-pc-cygwin --host=x86_64-pc-cygwin --target=x86_64-pc-cygwin --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --libexecdir=/usr/lib --enable-shared --enable-shared-libgcc --enable-static --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-bootstrap --enable-__cxa_atexit --with-dwarf2 --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=ada,c,c++,fortran,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-graphite --enable-threads=posix --enable-libatomic --enable-libcilkrts --enable-libgomp --enable-libitm --enable-libquadmath --enable-libquadmath-support --disable-libssp --enable-libada --disable-symvers --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --with-cloog-include=/usr/include/cloog-isl --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --with-system-zlib --enable-linker-build-id --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=gcc4-compatible
Thread model: posix
gcc version 6.4.0 (GCC)
```

x86_64-w64-mingw32:

```
$ x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.4.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: /cygdrive/i/szsz/tmpp/cygwin64/mingw64-x86_64/mingw64-x86_64-gcc-6.4.0-2.x86_64/src/gcc-6.4.0/configure --srcdir=/cygdrive/i/szsz/tmpp/cygwin64/mingw64-x86_64/mingw64-x86_64-gcc-6.4.0-2.x86_64/src/gcc-6.4.0 --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --localstatedir=/var --sysconfdir=/etc --docdir=/usr/share/doc/mingw64-x86_64-gcc --htmldir=/usr/share/doc/mingw64-x86_64-gcc/html -C --build=x86_64-pc-cygwin --host=x86_64-pc-cygwin --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --with-sysroot=/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root --with-build-sysroot=/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root --disable-multilib --disable-win32-registry --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-graphite --enable-libgomp --enable-libquadmath --enable-libquadmath-support --enable-libssp --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-libgomp --enable-libada --with-dwarf2 --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --with-tune=generic --with-cloog-include=/usr/include/cloog-isl --with-system-zlib --enable-threads=posix --libexecdir=/usr/lib
Thread model: posix
gcc version 6.4.0 (GCC)
```

SomeClass's hpp and cpp:

```
//.hpp
class SomeClass { 
    public:
        SomeClass (const SomeClass &copy);
        void allocateCstring (char *cs);
         ~SomeClass ();
    private:
        char *cstring;
};

//.cpp
void SomeClass::allocateCstring (char *cs) {
    char *temp = cs;
    int length = 0;

    do {
        length++;
    } while (*(temp++) != '\0');

    cstring = new char[length]; //local member
    while (length-- = 0) {
        *(cstring + length) = *(cs + length);
    }
}

SomeClass::SomeClass (const SomeClass &copy) {
    //perform deep copy here
    char *temp = copy.cstring;
    int length = 0;

    do {
        length++;
    } while (*(temp++) != '\0');

    cstring = new char[length];
    while (length-- > 0) {
        *(cstring + length) = *(copy.cstring + length);
    }
    std::cout << "Copied" << std::endl;
}

SomeClass::~SomeClass () {
    std::cout << "Destructor called." << std::endl;
    delete [] cstring;
}
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: What is `s`? Should that be `s1`?

Comment: Since you never do anything with `s2`, it might have optimized it away.

Comment: @Barmar Is really a compiler allowed to optimize away both copy constructor and destructor call in this case? What if they have side effects? I have tried that with GCC 7.2 complied with `-std=c++17` and no such elision occurred with similar code: https://wandbox.org/permlink/LwlCd4CchmQvt7lF

Comment: @Barmar , yes, changed it to s1. I will update the original question with more full code

Comment: If it can determine that there are no side effects I think it can.

Comment: @hrs How do you determine whether destructor is or isn't invoked?

Comment: @DanielLangr with std::cout . Updated OP with more code.

Comment: @Barmar , updated OP with more code. With both compilers i get the std::cout diagnostic messages. It's just with `mingw` version i don't get the destructor message for the `s2`. So i presume that memory is lost in the heap. This whole thing is a study, ofc, i don't need to stick with the mingw compiler. I just need to know if i'm doing something wrong?

Comment: @hrs Do you see the `"Copied"` message with both compilers? What if you try to print out the contents of `s2`, does it change anything?

Comment: @DanielLangr Yes, `"Copied"` shows for `SomeClass s2 = s1;` with both compilers. It's omitted here for brevity, but the copy operation is valid and can `std::cout << cstring;`.